# Sonata Admin, custom flashBag

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a formMapper Sonata. I have add the prePersist and preUpdate function who are performing some checks before approving changes.

If it fail, I would like to display a nice error message. I have seen that there is some flags who can use but nothing really interesting. Even more, a return false does not stop the action.

Des someone know how could I manage this feature ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a flash message in your hooks accessing the `getRequest` method.

```
public function prePersist($object) {
    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Error message');
}
```

To stop an action from inside an Admin hook, I found that the best way is to throw a `ModelManagerException`. This particular exception is, in fact, handled by the [CRUDController](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.x/Controller/CRUDController.php#L641).
Not too clean I have to admit, but effective.

Note: The way to access the flashbag may be a little different with respect to your SonataAdmin version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you don't get in the doc. [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) it says that in your controller you need to add

```
$session->getFlashBag()->add('key', 'message');
```

And to get it in the view :

```
  {% for message in app.session.flashbag.get('key') %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are probably searching for is a [custom validator constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

The validator will automatically check for all validator constraints when you submit a sonata form. If there's an error, the entity is not persisted and a nice message is displayed (depending on what constraint validation message you set).